# PHP script with firefox returns SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. OK with IE, Chrome, Edge

Tags: php, firefox

If I include the statement:

```
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

in a PHP script, then execute the script in debug mode in VS2022 Community, I get an error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

only when using Firefox.  I do not get the error with Edge, Chrome, or IE.

Taking the header statement out of the PHP and everything runs OK on all browsers.  PHP.INI has default charset utf-8; Removing charset=utf-8 from the header has no effect.

I believe I'm dealing with a char-set issue, but don't know where the issue lies.  The PHP file is on localhost and just does a database call to retrieve some rows from MySQL.

I can leave the header statement out, but I don't understand why the header fails.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: it could be a charset issue but without actual JSON that causes an error we can only guess

Comment: The post reference about utf-8 all the way resolved the issue